# Java, run another application in foreground

Tags: java, process, foreground

I want run another application from java code.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("cmd.exe");
```

Process is launched, but in background. How to make it run in foreground?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should tell cmd.exe that you want it to open in new window:

```
Process pr = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start");
```

Answer (score 5):

[Process#waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [commons-exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) when dealing with external processes.
In my opinion it is much easier to handle than using the Java Runtime class.

Tutorial : http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Run your command from a JDialog and after running it, use toBack().

```
final JDialog dlg = new javax.swing.JDialog(null, "test", JDialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
JButton button = new JButton("Select Me");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(
                    new java.io.File("/home/user/Downloads/jfreechart-1.0.13-US.pdf"));
            dlg.toBack();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e1);
        }
    }
});
```