# Why does a process run but not show?

Tags: java, process

I have a java application that downloads and runs another program. The problem I'm running into is that when it runs the program there is no visual; however, the process shows up in the Windows Task Manager.

Here's the relevant execution code:

```
String[] cmd = {System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + PACKAGE_PATH + onePackage};
log.info("Package downloaded to: " + cmd[0]);
new ProcessBuilder(cmd[0]).start();
```

I've also used a Runtime.exec() and that produced the same results.

Here's a Commons Exec version that produces the same result:

```
String line = "cmd.exe start /c " + "\"" + cmd[0] + "\""; 
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
```

One last bit of detail, it works fine on my Win7 desktop from Eclipse, but not on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I think you're actually looking for this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11984075/971423

Comment: @Welsh that would be great if I were using cmd.exe. In this case the cmd just means 'command' in the general sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();  
        Process pr = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c mspaint.exe");
    }
}
```

This will result in a `mspaint.exe` getting started up in the foreground compared to the background. However since you do it through `cmd.exe` that process ends immediately after `mspaint.exe` starts up resulting in the java program to finish its execution regardless of the status of the `mspaint.exe` which may be ok for your situation.

If you need to wait for it to finish, I would recommend looking at [`Commons Exec`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html)