# Runtime.exec() opening application in background

Tags: java, runtime.exec, awtrobot

I m using runtime.exec() to open an application and perform some task on it, but it opens in background and i'm not able to perform any task as planned, so can anybody suggest how to bring my app to foreground so that its active to perform the required task.
i'm using the below code

```
try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Beyond Compare 3\\BCompare.exe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    System.out.println("Running robot class");
     Robot rb;
    try 
    {
        rb = new Robot();
         rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

         Thread.sleep(3000);

         rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         Thread.sleep(3000);

    } 
    catch (AWTException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This might help you [Java, run another application in foreground][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983803/java-run-another-application-in-foreground

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the thread.sleep and try with below,

rb = new Robot();
rb.delay(3000);

It's opening for me